# NodeJS: firebase-tools firestore delete failing

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am attempting to delete a sub collection when the parent document is deleted.

I have created the following cloud function to do so:

```
import { firestore, logger } from 'firebase-functions';
import { recursiveDelete } from '../utils/db';

export const deleteListItems = firestore.document('owners/{owner}/lists/{list}').onDelete(snap => {
  const collPath = snap.ref.collection('items').path;
  logger.info('Why do you hate me?');
  logger.debug({ collPath });
  return recursiveDelete(collPath);
});

---------
db.ts
---------------------------------
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');

export const recursiveDelete = (path: string): Promise<any> => {
  console.debug({ project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT });
  console.debug({ token: functions.config().fb.token });

  return firebase_tools.firestore.delete(path, {
    project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
    token: functions.config().fb.token,
  });
};
```

From my logging, I can see that the path I'm trying to delete is correct, `owners/G-470728052545159171/lists/anime/items`. I can also see that the project and token values are present.

I am, however, seeing the following error in the cloud functions logs:

> ```
> deleteListItems 
> FirebaseError: Deletion failed. Errors: Failed to fetch documents to delete >= 3 times..
>    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/firestore/delete.js:272:32)
>    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
>    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
> ```

I ideally want the delete to be performed at the list doc level, but I thought that, that doc being deleted already might have been causing the error, which clearly it isn't.

I tried running the equivalent command in my console:

```
firebase firestore:delete -r -y owners/G-470728052545159171/lists/anime/items
```

This works as expected, even if the list doc (anime), is already deleted, so I'm not understanding why the one in the function isn't working.

**EDIT**: Set `DEBUG` env var

Debug output:

```
2:05:30.175 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.171Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
2:05:30.176 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.175Z] > authorizing via --token option
2:05:30.176 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.176Z] [iam] checking project watchlist-bot for permissions ["datastore.entities.delete","datastore.entities.list","firebase.projects.get"] 
2:05:30.246 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.244Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"] 
2:05:30.246 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.245Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token   
2:05:30.246 PM
deleteListItems
 <request body omitted> 
2:05:30.478 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.477Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400 {"cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","date":"Sat, 17 Apr 2021 18:05:30 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","expires":"Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","server":"scaffolding on HTTPServer2","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"} 
2:05:30.581 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.581Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 401 {"www-authenticate":"Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.com/\", error=\"invalid_token\"","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","date":"Sat, 17 Apr 2021 18:05:30 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","server-timing":"gfet4t7; dur=4","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"} 
2:05:30.581 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.581Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY {"error":{"code":401,"message":"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","status":"UNAUTHENTICATED"}} 
2:05:30.583 PM
deleteListItems
[2021-04-17T18:05:30.583Z] [iam] error while checking permissions, command may fail: FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

It seems there is an issue with my token, which I suspected, but I'm not sure why. I generated the token using `firebase login:ci` as they specified.
Then I set it using `firebase functions:config:set fb.token=***`.

Comment: Just before `require('firebase-tools');`, add in `process.env.DEBUG = true`. This should give some more (probably way too much) information about what's going on. The docs state that some functions require filesystem access, but I doubt this is one.

Comment: @samthecodingman I've included the interesting parts of my debug output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your log messages, your current token generated by `login:ci` is incorrectly missing the `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"` scope. Try updating your `firebase-tools` instance that you used to create the token and try generating a fresh token.

Regarding why this same error doesn't appear on your local system: On your system, `firebase-tools` makes use of your full account credential (to deploy code, etc) rather than a credential with targeted scopes.

Comment: This worked, thanks. But, I'm wondering: will this token expire?

Comment: @Ace The token generated is an OAuth 2 refresh token. Unless you revoke it [from your Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) (shown as *Firebase CLI*) or change the account's password, this token won't "expire". However, the access/ID tokens that are generated using it will have a 1 hour expiry.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.