# Firestore Delete Failing to Fetch Documents

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to implement a recursive delete in cloud functions, but the delete function is returning the error [firebase_functions/internal] FirebaseError: Deletion failed. Errors: Failed to fetch documents to delete >= 3 times..

It's very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67140838/nodejs-firebase-tools-firestore-delete-failing), but I tried updating firebase tools and getting a fresh token and no change. I tried getting the debug logs by adding in process.env.DEBUG = true, but I got a type error that it had to be a string - so I changed true to "true" and it doesn't seem to be giving me any logs (unless I just don't know where to look for them).

The function is deploying, although I am getting the message:

[2022-12-08T22:01:07.693Z] Could not find image for function projects/onama-produce/locations/australia-southeast1/functions/recursiveDelete

This is the function:

```
/* eslint @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires: "off" */

import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
process.env.DEBUG = "true";
const firebaseTools = require("firebase-tools");


/**
 * Initiate a recursive delete of documents at a given path.
 *
 * The calling user must be authenticated.
 *
 * This delete is NOT an atomic operation and it's possible
 * that it may fail after only deleting some documents.
 *
 * @param {string} data.path the document or collection path to delete.
 */
exports.recursiveDelete = functions
    .region("australia-southeast1")
    .runWith({
      timeoutSeconds: 540,
      memory: "2GB",
    })
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      // Only allow authorised users to execute this function.
      if (!(context.auth && context.auth.token)) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            "permission-denied",
            "Must be an administrative user to initiate delete."
        );
      }
      const path = data.path;
      console.log(
          `User ${context.auth.uid} has requested to delete path ${path}`
      );

      // Run a recursive delete on the given document or collection path.
      // The 'token' must be set in the functions config, and can be generated
      // at the command line by running 'firebase login:ci'.
      try {
        await firebaseTools.firestore
            .delete(path, {
              project: process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
              recursive: true,
              force: true,
              token: process.env.TOKEN,
            });

        return {
          path: path,
        };
      } catch (err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", String(err));
      }
    });
```

And this is the client-side code (written in flutter):

```
 /// Call the 'recursiveDelete' callable function with a path to initiate
  /// a server-side delete.
  void deleteAtPath(String path) async {
    print("delete: deleting at path " + path);
    try {
      final HttpsCallableResult deleteFnResult = await functions
          .httpsCallable('recursiveDelete')
          .call(<String, String>{
        "path": path,
      });
      print(deleteFnResult.toString());
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
      print("firebase error: " + e.toString() + " for deleting path " + path);
    } catch (e) {
      print("path delete error " + e.toString() + " for deleting path " + path);
    }
  }
```

```
  deleteUserProfile(String _uid) async {
    deleteAtPath(_userCollection.doc(_uid).path);
    deleteAtPath(_locationsCollection.doc(_uid).path);
    deleteEachProduct(productsFromUserProfileQuery(_uid));
    return;
  }
```

This is the error:

[Failed to fetch documents to delete error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cjMr.png)

And this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Also, I can delete via the command line fine, e.g.  `firebase firestore:delete users/iALet1LOthcw0Nx6FMgP6nOa3N83` works

I've been battling firebase functions for days, so any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I figured out how to access the logs and saw that for some reason the project was undefined. I swapped back to getting the project id from the deprecated process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT instead of process.env.GCP_PROJECT and it works now yay!